# Extracting specific data via coordinates using php pdfParser

Tags: php, parsing, text-parsing, pdf-parsing, pdfparser

I want to extract specific data from various pdfs that are 3-4 pages each.
I don't want to parse everything (all the text of each page) and then using for example regular expressions in order to match the data that i want.

So i was looking the documentation, and the php pdfParser has this function `$data = $pdf->getPages()[0]->getDataTm();` in which it is returnig you an array and it says that `You can extract transformation matrix (indexes 0-3) and x,y position of text objects (indexes 4,5).`
(https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/master/doc/Usage.md)

So i tried it and it is returning an array with all the data that i want, plus each data's coordinates..

Here an example of you to try it if you want.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Smalot\PdfParser\Parser;

$parser = new Parser();
$pdf = $parser->parseFile('pdfFile.pdf');

$data = $pdf->getPages()[0]->getDataTm();
print_r($data);
```

Now let's say i have the coordinates, but i don't know how to use them in order to find the exact data that i want.
I was looking the documentation for a function that you can apply the coordinates something like this `functionXYcoordinates("260", "120")` in order to get what i exaclty want from my pdf.. but I  couldn't find anything.

If anyone knows if there is a function like this in pdfParser, please let me know, or also feel free if you believe that extracting data via coordinates is a bad thing, and it is better by parsing all the pages and then using regular expression in order to match the specific data.